# Chaining subscriptions in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a function in my service as:

```
newGetClient(client_id, token):Observable<Response> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("authentication", token );
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let final_url = `${this.baseUrl}/${client_id}?model=client`

  return this.http.get(final_url, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

which I call in my controller as:

```
fetchClients() {
  this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[0], this.auth_token).subscribe( data => {
    this.c1 = this.parseClient(data)
    this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[1], this.auth_token).subscribe( data => {
      this.c2 = this.parseClient(data)
      this.generateKeys()
    })
  })
}

generateKeys() {
  this.keys = _.union(Object.keys(this.c1), Object.keys(this.c2))
  this.loaded = true
}
```

but I'm making the call to `fetchClients()` with 2 different `client_ids` and I need to make a seperate call to `generateKeys()` once both calls to fetch have been completed.

I feel as though nesting the calls to `newGetClient()` is incorrect so I'm wondering how to chain them so that I can call `generateKeys()` once both subscriptions are complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these two calls are not dependent on each other you can use `forkJoin()`:

```
const o1 = this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[0], this.auth_token);
const o2 = this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[1], this.auth_token);

Observable.forkJoin(o1, o2).subscribe(([result1, result2]) => {
  this.c1 = this.parseClient(result1);
  this.c2 = this.parseClient(result2);
  this.generateKeys();
});
```

If you want to be able to assign `c1` and `c2` as they arrive without waiting for both of the Observables to complete you could chain `o1` and `o2` with `do()`:

```
const o1 = this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[0], this.auth_token).do(res => this.c = res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [zip](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) to combine your two observables - it will emit when  both observables have emitted.

Something like this (note: it's not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
fetchClients() {
    rx.observable.zip(
        this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[0], this.auth_token).map(this.parseClient),
        this.clientService.newGetClient(this.client_ids[1], this.auth_token).map(this.parseClient)
    )
    .map(arrClients => _.union(Object.keys(arrClients[0]), Object.keys(arrClients[1])))
    .subscribe( clientUnion => {
        this.keys = clientUnion;
        this.loaded = true
      });
}
```